# Can't save negative decimal values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with Entity Framework code first. The error occurs when trying to save a negative decimal value into the SQL Server database. The model that I'm trying to save is listed below.

```
public class Material
{
        public Material()
        {
            Categories = new List<Category>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Taken { get; set; }
        public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

Here I'm trying to set the precision of the decimal (Latitude/Longitude) in the model Material.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Material>().Property(x => x.Latitude).HasPrecision(8, 7);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Material>().Property(x => x.Longitude).HasPrecision(8, 7);
 }
```

In the database the column information looks like this:

```
dbo.Materials.Latitude (decimal(8, 6), null)

dbo.Materials.Longitude (decimal(8, 6), null)
```

If I try to save a negative value like `-1m` everything works fine. But as soon is I try to save any bigger value or value with decimals like `-123` or `-123.123456` the data context always throws an exception when saving.

The exception I'm getting is this:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

Looking in to the inner exception we can see that this might be the cause of the problem:

> {"Parameter value '-117.246108' is out of range."}

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you tell me the type of datacell?

Comment: What does the schema look like for that field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know with extension "HasPrecision(8, 7)", you are defining decimal to have a total 8 digits; with right side having at most 7 digits.
The decimal -117.246108 has 9 digits, try changing "HasPrecision(9, 7)".

Answer (score 1):

It behaves exactly as you configured your model. `HasPrecision(8,7)` means that total number of allowed digits on both sides of decimal point is 8 and total number of digit on the right side of decimal point is 7. So you can have only single digit on the left side of the decimal point. To store '-117.246108' you need at least precision 9 and scale 6.